# Colorscheme for vim works on termite and not on urxvt

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, color-scheme

I've tried to install a bunch of colorscheme for vim, and they don't work on Urxvt terminal, while on Termite the only problem is that when I scroll the colors get messed up.

**Color scheme problem**
[On the left Urxvt, on the right Termite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTr1k.jpg)

**Echo of $TERM**
URXVT: `rxvt-unicode-256color`
Termite: `xterm-termite`

That's my [.vimrc](http://pastebin.com/RRwCf0bF) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it wasn't working because of theese lines:
`set termguicolors`
`set t_Co=256`
That's the [.vimrc](http://pastebin.com/iNT0mtjN) fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably check your **.Xresources/.Xdefaults ** the problem can be from there . 
termite uses  *~/.config/termite/config*
and Urxvt uses *.Xresources* .

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: @Ziyadsk Thank you for the tip!